How to make async I/O more efficient?
I am using the following method to read from a very large file and write the results to a new file.
The amount of data read from the input file and written to a new file can very wildly, from a few KiB to a couple GiB. I am using this method in a program to parse/extract a filesystem binary image - so this method gets used a lot.
How can I improve the efficiency of this method? It is at least 2x slower (in the best case) than a synchronous version I wrote.
private async Task WriteFileContentsAsync(Inode inode, FileStream outputStream)
{
    int remainder = (int)(inode.Size % BlockSize);
    remainder = (remainder == 0) ? (int)BlockSize : remainder;

    List<long> dataPointers = GetDataPointersForInode(inode);
    byte[] data = new byte[BlockSize];

    List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < dataPointers.Count - 1)
    {
        FileStream.Seek(dataPointers[i], SeekOrigin.Begin);
        i++;
        taskList.Add(FileStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, (int)BlockSize));
        taskList.Add(outputStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, (int)BlockSize));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);

    if (dataPointers.Count != 0) // handle remainder
    {
        FileStream.Seek(dataPointers[i], SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int numBytesRead = FileStream.Read(data, 0, remainder);
        if (numBytesRead == remainder)
        {
            outputStream.Write(data, 0, remainder);
        }
    }
}

Some things that may or may not be helpful to mention:

Data is read a block at a time from the image, and the blocks of data for a file may or may not be local to each other. (I think that blocks are typically local to each other, though.)
blocksize is a variable that's defined by the filesystem I'm trying to parse, it can be as large as 4 KiB
The filesize (i.e. how many bytes this method will read) is known prior to the call
Sorry if I'm not including enough information - I am new to asynchronous programming (and I guess I/O techniques beyond simple reads/writes). Thanks in advance


If I understand your code correctly, you have multiple asynchronous tasks all reading and writing to the same shared buffer. There is no way that is safe. So before you worry about performance I would consider safety and correctness.

I don't understand why sharing a buffer between the input and output stream is unsafe. Could you please explain?

You are going to and fro FileStream: FileStream.Seek(...) which means that you can well read the file over and over again. Could we change it into sequential read: we read fragment and decide which order it is? Or sort dataPointers in order to move forward only.

typically each stream supports one active read or write operation - async is fine, but the individual async operations need to be sequential to each-other, not concurrent; you're also using a single buffer (data) for all of the operations, and you're not even waiting for the read to complete before starting the write of that buffer. What you have here is simply chaos: I'd be amazed if it even completes, but there is exactly zero chance of the results being correct in any way.

oh, and BTW: Read and ReadAsync don't guarantee to read a full buffer; you must check the return value - typically you read in a loop

finally: concurrent access to a single stream would reduce throughput, not increase it - asking for data from 400 places in a file at the same time will just overload the IO controller, even if the API supported it, which it doesn't

I would highly recommend writing some unit tests to verify correct behavior. Unit tests may not be consistent if there are race conditions or other threading problems, but they can still help. They can also help with debugging and profiling. Also, IO tend to perform best when doing large sequential operations, so in some cases it can be faster to just read everything into memory, modify and write out, rather than doing a bunch of random IO access.

As I mentioned in comments, there are a lot of problems in the current code;  a broad gist of how this could be implemented follows; key points:

there's only one active operation per stream at any time
a single buffer is only being used for a single purpose at any time
we're waiting for reads into the buffer to complete before writing the contents out to anywhere
it checks the return value from read operations and reacts accordingly

As per the comments in the code: this does still have capacity for improvement, potentially doubling the throughput by overlapping write and read, but that is much more complex, and honestly: I think you should focus on correctness for now.
// this approach uses one write per read; you could also choose to perform *all*
// the reads for a block, then a single write; it could also be further
// optimized by using *two* buffers and *overlapping* the write with the *next*
// read (making sure to alternate the buffers)
byte[] data = new byte[BlockSize];
foreach (var dataPointer in GetDataPointersForInode(inode))
{
    FileStream.Seek(dataPointer, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    int remaining = (int)BlockSize, read;
    while (remaining > 0 &&
        (read = (await FileStream.ReadAsync(data, 0, remaining))) > 0)
    {
        await outputStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, read);
        remaining -= read;
    }
    if (remaining != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
// TODO: remainder

